# std::thread error for target taking pointer args

Tags: c++, c++14, stdthread

I have a setup similar to the following,

**A.hpp**

```
#include <thread>

class A {

    static void foo(char*, char*);

    void bar() {

        char* char_start = (char*) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        char* char_end = char_start + (100 * sizeof(char)) - 1;

        std::thread t(foo, char_start, char_end);
        t.join();

        return;
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main() { 
    A.bar();            

    return 0;
}
```

I compile with

```
g++ -std=c++14 -pthread main.cpp
```

And get:

```
usr/include/c++/4.9/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(long unsigned int*, char*, char*))(long unsigned int*, char*, char*, const bool&)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:140:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(long unsigned int*, char*, char*, const bool&); _Args = {long unsigned int*, char*, char*}]’
A.cpp:100:151:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1665:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(long unsigned int*, char*, char*))(long unsigned int*, char*, char*, const bool&)>’
typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                         ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1695:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(long unsigned int*, char*, char*))(long unsigned int*, char*, char*, const bool&)>’
 _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

I can't interpret this error. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I apologize as I left out the fact that `foo` also had a default bool argument set to `false`. Getting rid of the default argument let's it compile.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code sample in your question does not produce the error.

Comment: Which version of g++ are you using? Does it compile if you try `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @Mark The code doesn't compile as is and it has nothing to do with the standards mode.

Comment: @remyabel The code *does* compile as is, with [both GCC and Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfcab0c7dd5a73dd)

Comment: @Columbo That's because you *changed* the obviously fake code, aka, why the OP needs to post an MCVE.

Comment: @Columbo: That code is completely different. "As is" my arse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A.bar()` is not a valid language construct. You can invoke `bar()` only on an instance of `A`, not on the typename `A`.

By changing

```
A.bar();
```

to

```
A a;
a.bar();
```

and providing a dummy implementation of `A::foo()`, I was able to build and run the program.

Comment: Worth explaining _why_?